# Write/Read to Windows Event Log

Tags: api, vba, event-log

Is there an easy way to write to and read from the windows event log in VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the standard API calls.  [See HOWTO: Write to the Windows NT Event Log from Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154576) This is fairly old but should get you started.

Note, however, that this code uses a default source.  (Run the event log to see what I mean by source.) I haven't run tihs code in Access so I don't know what the default source is for Access.  In VB6 thuogh it was something generic with VB 6 runtime or some such.   If you visit the thread [ReportEvent and MessageDLL problem Options](http://groups.google.ca/group/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/browse_thread/thread/d828f584a8297188/4058414464203cd9) it states you need to run an install program with admin privileges to add your app name and path to   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\ So this could get even more complex when it comes to getting a distinguishable source in the event log.